# Respond with 64bit Integer with Node.js

Tags: node.js, integer

I'm creating a web application API that is required to respond to all HTTP POST requests with a JSON object.

The one stumbling block I have is that one of those JSON fields needs to contain a 64bit int, however, natively Node.js only support 64bit doubles and therefore does not include the level of precision required.

No calculations need to be done with this integer it is simply a request 'ID' that allows the service using the API to understand the response from Node.js. Unfortunately converting the value to a string would break the service accessing this API, therefore, the response needs to be a valid 64bit int.

Is there any way to respond with a 64bit int within the response JSON?

Comment: Does the client-side javascript need to be able to read these ints as well (That is the client side is JavaScript and it also needs to read the data)

Comment: The service that I am communicating with is another web server written in C. It POSTs some json to my service including the 64bit int and I'm required to respond including the same 64 bit int as an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript follows ECMA-262 standards, by which all numbers (integers and floats) in JavaScript are 64-bit floating point numbers ([IEEE_754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Double-precision_64_bit)). It can use upto 53 bit for integeral values. So natively you cannot handle 64 bit integer operations.

Use [node-int64](https://npmjs.org/package/node-int64) package for 64bit integer support in node

Comment: You can easily store them as bits in signed arrays in node as long as you don't treat them as 64 bit ints.

Comment: Thanks. These modules appear fine for storing 64bit ints, however, I'm having difficulty getting the 64bit int from the http post.